# ASP IdentityFramework: Added personalized property to AspNetUsers table but IdentityUser model was not updated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Quick question.
I added a personalized property to the AspNetUser's table named "WebSiteName" and now I am modifying the register page to be able to enter the new information but I found that the IdentityUser model was not updated and I am unable to set my property. What am I missing? Do I need to scaffold something again?

I already added the migration and updated the database.

This is how I added the prop:

```cs
public class PublikoUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string WebSiteName { get; set; }
    }

public class PublikoIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PublikoUser>
    {
        public PublikoIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<PublikoIdentityDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        } 
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution Just needed to update Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml and replace IdentityUser with PublikoUser like so:

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<PublikoUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.